# Sharing image on flickr getting error in android studio

Tags: flickr

```
private void load(OAuth oauth) {
        if (oauth != null) {
            System.out.println("file :- "+file);
            UploadPhotoTask taskUpload = new UploadPhotoTask(this, new File(myDir,path));
            System.out.println("taskUpload :- "+taskUpload);
            taskUpload.setOnUploadDone(new UploadPhotoTask.onUploadDone() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            taskUpload.execute(oauth);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error on Oauth. I have added Oauth key and secret key but still getting error on Oauth. Please it will be very helpful if give any suggestion.Thanks in advance.